# VS2010 C# not including correct .net framework version in target

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am doing maintenance work on a VS2010 C# project built against .net v3.5.

I recently changed the project Target Framework properties to the latest version listed (v4) - due to an expectation of using a version of .net that is actually included in Win10 by default - and rebuilt without any apparent issues.

Unfortunately the embedded dependency in the generated .exe is still for .net v2.0.50727 (which is what is reported for v3.5 AFAIK) and the target machine (a clean install of Win10) is asking to install .net 3.5.

Using MS VS2010 v10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel.
Unfortunately upgrading the build tools isn't an option (building the program with VS2015 works just fine).

I have gone googling but don't seem to have found any similar reports.

Based on some of the comments already posted, I seem to have not made myself entirely clear - hopefully the following will help.

1) the intention/requirement is to be able to install this app on a clean install of Win10 **without** needing **any** further downloads. (installing .net 3.5 is easy to do, just not what is wanted)

2) the ultimate build environment for this is automated, visualized and not in my control and therefore upgrading the tool chain is a **major** pain that I'd like to avoid if possible.

3) AFAIK there are **no** third party libraries involved.  All of the listed references (dll's) are v4.0.30319.

4) this is a XAML-based development, one part of three projects in the solution - the other entries are the installer and a C# custom installation library.  As far as I can tell everything is set for .net v4.

Comment: curious question Peter, does your exe dependent on some external library that they perhaps compiled for 3.5?

Comment: Go to your project, click Add Reference, go to standard libraries tab and see, some assemblies are selected, like **System**. Navigate to it and see what version is showing in the grid

Comment: "Unfortunately upgrading the build tools isn't an option"? Build tools for VS 2015 and 2017 are freely available from Microsoft, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 So for .NET applications, you don't need the full VS in some cases.

Comment: The .NET Framework is considered a component of the Windows OS.  I think you install it by going to the Windows features tool (I can't check - I have a very locked down box right now).  But it's "Turn Windows Features On and Off" in Win10

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately the embedded dependency in the generated .exe is still for .net v2.0.50727 (which is what is reported for v3.5 AFAIK) and the target machine (a clean install of Win10) is asking to install .net 3.5

So there is some dependency in your project that targets that version of .NET. It could just be that you need to `Build > Clean Solution` and with a `Build > Rebuild Solution` the problem is solved.

Otherwise, assuming some library does require some .NET 3.x library, the installation request is entirely correct. Windows 10 does **not** have an option for installing .NET 2.0 and another for installing .NET 3.5. If you search for `Turn Windows features on or off` you will see this:

[image]

*Any* dependency on a .NET 2.x-3.x library will trigger the activation/installation of the first feature in the dialog.

As far as I can see, you have 2 options:

1. Move *everything* to a framework supported by Microsoft, most preferably .NET 4.7.2 given support and security.
2. Deal with the installation process and understand that Microsoft does not install these versions of .NET in purpose. You can, however, add these installers as a prerequisite and even bundle them with your installation, but that won't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who have tried to help me!

The issue has been resolved.

There appear to have been two causes for this issue and my confusion:

1. it turns out that the blank install of Win10 that the testing was being performed on was not entirely clean - the pre-installed network drivers/utilities from intel also had a .Net v3.5 dependency...
2. one of the embedded resources in the project was effectively a uncompressed tar-ball containing a number of files; including an executable that had the dependency on .net v3.5 - this was a binary blob stored in svn so the content was had not been updated for several years (ie well before my involvement) ...

With both of these issues addressed it would appear that my problem is solved, so once again thank you for your feedback, suggestions and patience,

PeterT :->